# Facebook page_fan query returning incomplete results

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to grab the Facebook pages that my friends liked.

```
SELECT uid,page_id,type,profile_section,created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I noticed that some data is missing from the result set, therefore I queried the table for individual user ids, as follows:

```
SELECT uid,page_id,type,profile_section,created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid={id1}
SELECT uid,page_id,type,profile_section,created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid={id2}
```

...

Apparently for some friend ids is working, but for some others the query returns empty result.

I thought that maybe those missing users have some privacy settings not allowing apps to pull data from their accouns.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `I thought that maybe those missing users have some privacy settings not allowing apps to pull data from their accouns.` this

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a valid access token when making this request?

If you look at the documentation for the page_fan table it explains what access tokens are needed

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

> To read the page_fan table you need:
>
> > - any valid access_token if it is public (visible to anyone on
> >       Facebook).
> > - user_likes permissions if querying the current user.
> > - friends_likes permissions if querying a user's friend.

Comment: The link you mention does not mention these permissions. Perhaps this has changed after your post. There is a separate link that mentions that to access page_fan (http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL:page_fan) you don't need any access_token or key (which is wrong) but my tests have shown that no user_likes is necessary for this query and am keen to ascertain whether it will be consistent.